# Automatic UTF-8 encoding in Node.js HTTP client

Tags: xml, encoding, response, httpclient, node.js

There I am trying to load XML content from a remote host using Node.js.

The problem is that German "umlaute" like "ä" are broken. Like in the browser this usually is a simple encoding problem. But since the XML content on the remote host is encoded in iso-8859-2" I had no success getting the letters back to work.

The functionality is very simple. I simply use the default HTTP client integrated in Node.js to connect to a remote host with a simple get request.

Some environment facts:

- The remote system uses "iso-8859-2" encoding.
- The encoding is currently set in the response header.
- The characters are unrecoverable broken in the data (chunk) received by `response.onData(chunk)`

Node.js is running on version 0.2 on da default Debian server.

The code is based on the default httpClient like described in the Node.js documentation.

I tried the following:

```
response.defaultAsciiEncoding true/false
response.encoding = UFT-8/ascii
```

I used a UTF-8 encoder/decoder to encode/decode the chunk. After this failed I tried to encode/decode the whole response body.

I am not very familiar with using buffers, and I guess the problem must be in that direction. Or Node.js (or the httpClient) simply can't handle other encoding types by default witch is my second guess. In this case I need to write my own HTTP client using the net lib I think. I just want to make sure I don't walk into the wrong direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick poke around the Node.js source and it seems like svick is right: Node.js doesn't support the ISO encoding. You can, however, get at the response as a binary stream and then either return it to the browser with your own encoding or use node-iconv (again as svick suggested).

Here's a little example: http://gist.github.com/576884

Comment: response.setEncoding("binary"); Did the trick i can't believe i didn't try that. Somehow i only tried using ascii here. For a quick prototype i used php.js utf8_encode. Works perfectly. Thanks for the answers and the link to the iconv bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the encoding parameter in the XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" ?>
<xml>
  <!-- whatever -->
</xml>
```

XML files default to UTF-8 unless you explicitly declare their encoding.

Comment: The remote source is dynamic and not under my control. But yes the xml version and encoding is set. I uploaded a sampleResponse to my server. I may add a node.js script as well to reproduce the error. The sample location is http://node.geht-ab.net/original.html

Comment: @age: Not sure what this is supposed to be? It is served as text/html with no encoding parameter.

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot so simulate the header correctly.  http://node.geht-ab.net/original.php 

I just added the Content-type header. Just the doctype of the xml is set to iso-8859-1 the response itself has no encoding information. Here is the original:

Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:181706
Content-Type:text/xml
Date:Sun, 12 Sep 2010 02:43:40 GMT
Server:Apache

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Node.js can't work with encoding other than UTF-8. Maybe using something like [node-iconv](http://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv/tree/) should work.

Comment: The problem here is there is, i can find no point / event to access the raw data. They look touched to me at response.onData(chunk). I'll may check the node.js libs to see whats going on. But in case i use the net.socket on port 80. The bindings you found couldt be usefull.