# Node.js request turns umlauts to �

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

I'm doing the following request (using request/request) against a web service:

```
return request.postAsync({
    url,
    charset: 'Cp1252', // I also tried utf-8
    encoding: null, //
    // I also tried Cp1252 -> unknown encoding,
    // I also tried utf-8 and nothing at all
    headers: {
         "Accept": "application/octet-stream, text, text/plain, text/xml",
         "Accept-Encoding": "UTF-8",
         'Content-Type': "text/plain; charset=Cp1252;", // also tried utf-8, ISO-8859-1
         "User-Agent": "me"
    }
}).spread((res, body) => {
    body = body.toString();  // I also tried without toString();
    let ws = fs.createWriteStream('hhh.csv');
    ws.write(body);
    ws.end();
```

Whatever I do, umlauts are turned into `�`.

Those are the headers the web service sends back:

```
'content-type': 'text; charset=Cp1252',
'content-length': '1895980',
vary: 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent'
```

I'm trying this for days with no luck at all. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a list of question/answers that didn't solve my problem so far:

- *[Umlauts broken when doing get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119411/umlauts-broken-when-doing-get-request)*
- *[Problems making http-post requests with German umlauts (ä ö ü) or special chars (ß) with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807252/problems-making-http-post-requests-with-german-umlauts-%C3%A4-%C3%B6-%C3%BC-or-special-chars)*
- *[Send umlauts from Node.js to iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523058/send-umlauts-from-nodejs-to-ios)*
- *[Automatic UTF-8 encoding in Node.js HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691768/automatic-utf-8-encodeing-in-node-js-http-client)*
- *[Custom HTTP header value - trying to pass umlaut characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489832/custom-http-header-value-trying-to-pass-umlaut-characters)*
- *[How to get UTF-8 in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267274/how-to-get-utf-8-in-node-js)*
- *[How to get i18next-node to display umlauts the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277858/how-to-get-i18next-node-to-display-umlauts-the-right-way)*
- *[How do I URl encode something in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554039/how-do-i-url-encode-something-in-node-js)*

Can it be that one of the following causes my input string to not be UTF-8?

```
let hash = crypto.createHmac("sha256", this.options.Signer);
this.query['Signature'] = hash.update(stringToSign).digest("base64");
```

signer is a string containing `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `+`, and `/`.

`this.query['Signature']` is part of the URL.

Comment: What are the exact characters you are sending? How are they currently encoded and what is the current character set for them?

Comment: In the place where the umlaut is "still" umlaut.

Comment: "node js request turns umlauts to �"  "Whatever I do, umlauts are turned into �." --- what these phrases mean then?

Comment: What are the exact characters you are sending? How are they currently encoded and what is the current character set for them?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `defaultEncoding` of your [`writeStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)? i.e. `fs.createWriteStream('hhh.csv', {defaultEncoding: 'utf8'});`

Comment: The url does not open `This webpage is not available DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Comment: Good. The problem is solved then.

Comment: Well, you mentioned that AWS is capable of sending utf-8 encoded data. Which means everything works fine. Otherwise provide more data as I asked 20 minutes ago.

Comment: My comment 20 minutes ago had nothing to do with keys. Just read the first comment once again, please.

Comment: If it's a proper utf-8 - then it's sent as utf-8 and then there is no problem with it. If it's utf-8 not sure why you put some other encoding but not utf-8.

Comment: Have you tried cURLing to the web service without using Node? It may be an issue with the service you are using

Comment: Done. PS: your solution is simply a workaround: you haven't fixed a problem, but consequences. Be prepared to be beaten by it once again some time later.

Comment: But what could the problem really be? I double checked the files encoding as well as querystrings configuration, it's all UTF8. Nothing else touches the data.  I will read up the document you just sent me tomorrow, and have another look at requests source, but I really can't find what I'm missing. @zerkms. Btw. icons takes quite long to convert, so I'll definitely have to have another look. Thanks for the deletion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved it, using [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) and setting request's encoding¹ to `null`, making it return the body as a Buffer. Here is my now working configuration:

```
return request.getAsync({
        url,
        encoding: null,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text, text/plain, text/xml",
            "Accept-Encoding": "UTF-8",
            'Content-Type': "text/plain; charset=utf-8;",
            "User-Agent": "me"
        }
    }).spread((res, body) => {
        let a = iconv.decode(new Buffer(body), 'cp1252');
        // now a is holding a string with correct Umlauts and ß
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040643/nodejs-encoding-using-request